NaN result using ShengBTE
I tried using ShengBTE t get the thermal conductivity of PE after performing phonon calculations using quantum espresso. When I used version 1.5.0 ShengBTE I got some numbers at the beginning of the output file and then keep getting NaN instead of numbers. I would like to know the reasons behind that please and how to solve it.
Thanks

We would likely need to see your input and output files to have a sense of what could cause this.

Thank you. I've tried to paste the code but there is a message stating that's it's too long. I'm not sure if I can attach the code as file. Please help. Thank you

Commenters aren't notified automatically of any messages, you need to tag them if you want them to know about it, like this @Tyberius . In answer to your question, is pastebin any good?

Have you checked that there are no imaginary ("negative") frequencies?
